# Cannot implicitly convert string to Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Activity

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am working on Bot Framework, and want some help.

I want to show a new login card. For  that I am creating a new activity because I want Bot to show that login card when the chat loads.

I have this code with me: 
[image]

As you can see in the above code, when I am writing:

```
Activity activity = turnContext.Activity.ToString()
```

It gives me error stating:

> Cannot implicitly convert from string to Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Activity.

To check if this works, I wrote:

```
Activity activity = (Activity)turnContext.Activity.ToString()
```

but still no luck.

What am I missing here? And what is the correct method to create an activity??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the property you are using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.turncontext.activity?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_TurnContext_Activity

> Gets the activity associated with this turn; or null when processing a proactive message.

So your code would build like this:

```
Activity activity = turnContext.Activity;
```

Comment: +1 and accept. It worked. I put explicit conversion like this: Activity activity = (Activity) turnContext.Activity; And the error's gone. Thank you so much for your help! :)